# Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables

Tags: c#, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I am trying to create and execute Shims from MS unit testcases in Visual Studio 2019. But, getting following error. How to resolve the following error. Thanks in advance.

**Errror:**

```
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.
  Source=Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.ResolveProfilerPath()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.IntelliTraceInstrumentationProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationRuntime.InitializeUnitTestIsolationInstrumentationProvider()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.Shims.ShimRuntime.CreateContext()
   at Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()
```

Shim is not creating and unit test is throwing the error while creating the shim context.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.